# how to clear jupyter notebook cell code from the memory after execution

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, jupyter

A visualizing code consumes 1gb+ of ram memory and notebook gets unresponsive. Is there any solution to remove it from memory without hurting other codes?. Restarting kernel isn't fruitful. Thank you

Comment: Hi, have you tried %reset -f  or use del var1 ... on the variables or import gc
gc.collect() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923415/release-memory-after-del-in-jupiter-notebook . Best

Comment: thanks. i get to know that python didn't have manual memory management. this del var1 and reset are making this worse. i dont want to delete variable just wanna remove folium graph from the memory after execution.

Answer (score 2):

IPython notebook stores cells and cell outputs in variables like `__`, `_1`, `_i3`. Call function `globals()` to check what is stored in those variables and delete those if needed using `%xdel` (for example `%xdel _3`).

Comment: Thanks for this! It might be useful to run the following snippet: `for varname in [x for x in globals() if x.startswith("_") and x[1:].isnumeric()]: %xdel {varname}`

Comment: Apparently there is also `%reset out` and a way to disable cache; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808904/prevent-ipython-from-storing-outputs-in-out-variable

Answer (score 0):

I had 6GB files for Pandas handling and cleaning. In a loop execution from file folder each next file was processed two times slower than the previous one (43 min, 86, 125, 254 min, etc.). Restarting kernel was not an option.
I just added one line for deleting variable (Pandas dataframe in my case) on the bottom of each cell. It solves the day for me!

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')

#any amount of lines for your actions

#after the next line memory becomes clean and ready to start with a new cell. The same approach at the end of a loop. 

del data
```